# How can I save a Jupyter Notebook (iPython notebook) programmatically?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to save a notebook (like clicking the "disk" icon in the toolbar) via a code block. Reason: I'd like to use `nbconvert` via a `%%bash` magic to save HTML and slide versions, but that converts what's on disk, not what's running.

I'm not looking to do this every time I save (for which I see some config that can be set up), but only selectively for some of my notebooks. I'm looking to be able to "Run All" and have the last few cells create the additional files reflecting the fresh data on screen at the moment.

I've tried `%save` and `%notebook` magics, but neither does quite what I'm looking for (the best I can tell).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hacky way to do it is using the `%%javascript` notebook magic to run the command

```
require(["base/js/namespace"],function(Jupyter) {
    Jupyter.notebook.save_checkpoint();
});
```

This accesses the global notebook instance (when on the notebook page this is the current notebook) and manually triggers a save and checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks for this... it's clever and does the job.

Comment: Can also we specify the folder path and the file name for the notebook to be saved as? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Here is a reusable version of @louise-davies answer in the form of a python function;

```
from IPython.display import Javascript

script = '''
require(["base/js/namespace"],function(Jupyter) {
    Jupyter.notebook.save_checkpoint();
});
'''

def notebook_save():
    Javascript(script)
    print('This notebook has been saved')
```

UPDATE:

I think the previous solution was broken but recent updates to jupyter notebook. It appears that `Javascript` cannot be invoked inside of a function. However it still works if called outside the context of a function.

```
from IPython.display import Javascript

script = '''
require(["base/js/namespace"],function(Jupyter) {
    Jupyter.notebook.save_checkpoint();
});
'''
Javascript(script)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using %%avascript and JQuery:

```
%%javascript
$("#save-notbook button").trigger('click');
```